# Rails 4 - Simple Form with Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

How do you set alternative CSS for simple form labels. The default is black bold. I want to change the font and weight.  I can't see anything in the config files for either simple form or simple form bootstrap to do this.  Is there a way to change the config?

Comment: You can create a separate css file to create your own set of styles.

Comment: how do you override default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is to add css in **application.css**,

```
label{
font-family: sans-serif,
font-weight: normal
}
```

Or else you can create a new stylesheet under **app/assets/stylesheets/** folder, for eg- **custom.css**, 
**app/assets/stylesheets /custom.css**-

```
label{
    font-family: sans-serif,
    font-weight: normal
    }
```

Add this line to enable rails see your css, **config/initializers/assets.rb**-

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css )
```

and include it in your layout file or on any page like this below **bootstrap.css**:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "custom.css" %>
```